# Grails links contains context path on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm having grails (`2.4.4`) application that is deploing from war (war name is equal to app name not ROOT.war) with Tomcat autoDeploy. Context in Grails `Config.groovy` is set to `/` (`grails.app.context = /`), link to server is `myapp.com` (not `myapp.com/appName`, because my provider lets me to do such binding).

My problem is that when I'm running my app (from war) all links have `/appName` prefix, i.e. `<asset:stylesheet src="mycss.css" />` changes to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/appName/assets/css/mystyle.css">`. Proper link in this case should look like this: `href="/assets/css/mystyle.css"`

FYI running app with `grails prod run-appp` works fine.

Comment: Have you properly configured your grails.serverURL in your grails-app/conf/Config.groovy file?

Comment: yep, I have ```grails.serverURL="myapp.com"```